# Multi values passing through a single parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Example
     (@BranchCode AS INT,
      @Department VARCHAR(8000),
      @DateFrom AS DATETIME,
      @DateTo AS DATETIME,
      @TransactionNumber AS NVARCHAR(30)
      -- @Delimiter char(1)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @Sql = 'Select 
                    Mast.Branch_code, Mast.purerq_id as purerq_id,
                    Max(Mast.purreq_date) as purreq_date, Max(Mast.Dept_code) as Dept_code, 
                    Max(Mast.purreq_desc) as purreq_desc,
                    Sum(Det.purreq_qty2) as purreq_qty2, 
                    Det.Item_Code, Max(Mast.purreq_docecNo) as DocNo,
                    Sum(IsNull(Det.purreq_qty1,0)) as purreq_qty1,
                    IsNull(Det.purerq_TranNo,'') as purerq_TranNo,
                    IsNull(Max(Mast.purerq_adduserid),'') as Adduserid,
                    Max(Det.ItemPacking_Code) as ItemPacking_Code
                From 
                    tbl_purreqMaster Mast, tbl_purreq_detail1 Det
                Where 
                    Mast.Branch_code = Det.Branch_code And 
                    Mast.purerq_id = Det.purerq_id And
                    Mast.purreq_date Between ' + @DateFrom + ' And ' + @DateTo + ' And 
                    Mast.Dept_code IN (' + REPLACE( @Department, '''','') + ')  
                    Mast.Branch_code = ' + CAST(@BranchCode AS VARCHAR)   + ' AND
                    Mast.purreq_docecNo =' + @TransactionNumber + ' 
                Group By 
                    Mast.Branch_code, Mast.purerq_id, Det.Item_Code, Det.purerq_TranNo'

    PRINT @Sql 
    --exec sp_executesql @Sql
END
GO


EXEC Example 1,'7,8','2017-10-01 00:00:00','2017-10-30 00:00:00','ALIA/PURQGEN/0000001'
```

This query shows this error

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Example, Line 18
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

However I have tried replace and cast functions to resolve this but I found no solution

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `@params` that go along with [**`sp_executesql`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql) for the parameters that do not need to be concatenated to your executed string. I would also recommend some more processing on `@Department` to prevent [sql injection](http://bobby-tables.com/).

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Example
     (@BranchCode AS INT,
      @Department VARCHAR(8000),
      @DateFrom AS DATETIME,
      @DateTo AS DATETIME,
      @TransactionNumber AS NVARCHAR(30)
      -- @Delimiter char(1)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX), @Params nvarchar(8000);
    set @Params = '@BranchCode INT, @DateFrom DATETIME, @DateTo DATETIME, @TransactionNumber NVARCHAR(30)'

    SET @Sql = 'Select 
                    Mast.Branch_code, Mast.purerq_id as purerq_id,
                    Max(Mast.purreq_date) as purreq_date, Max(Mast.Dept_code) as Dept_code, 
                    Max(Mast.purreq_desc) as purreq_desc,
                    Sum(Det.purreq_qty2) as purreq_qty2, 
                    Det.Item_Code, Max(Mast.purreq_docecNo) as DocNo,
                    Sum(IsNull(Det.purreq_qty1,0)) as purreq_qty1,
                    IsNull(Det.purerq_TranNo,'') as purerq_TranNo,
                    IsNull(Max(Mast.purerq_adduserid),'') as Adduserid,
                    Max(Det.ItemPacking_Code) as ItemPacking_Code
                From tbl_purreqMaster Mast
                  inner join tbl_purreq_detail1 Det
                    on Mast.Branch_code = Det.Branch_code
                   and Mast.purerq_id = Det.purerq_id
                Where Mast.purreq_date Between @DateFrom and @DateTo
                  and Mast.Dept_code IN (' + REPLACE( @Department, '''','') + ')
                  and Mast.Branch_code = @BranchCode
                  and Mast.purreq_docecNo = @TransactionNumber
                Group By 
                    Mast.Branch_code, Mast.purerq_id, Det.Item_Code, Det.purerq_TranNo'

    PRINT @Sql 
    --exec sp_executesql @Sql, @Params, @BranchCode, @DateFrom, @DateTo, @TransactionNumber
END
```

---

The best approach in SQL Server 2008 would be using table valued parameters for `@DepartmentId`:

- [Table-Valued Parameters - msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(v=sql.100).aspx)
- [User-Defined Table Types - msdn](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [SQL Server 2008 Table-Valued Parameters and C# Custom Iterators: A Match Made In Heaven! - Leonard Lobel](https://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2009/07/29/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters-and-c-custom-iterators-a-match-made-in-heaven/)
- [Table Value Parameter Use With C# - Jignesh Trivedi](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/table-value-parameter-use-with-C-Sharp/)
- [Using Table-Valued Parameters in SQL Server and .NET - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html)

Answer (score 0):

SQLZim's solution should work.  But since he doesn't mention it, I will point out that the reason for the error is this line:

```
Mast.purreq_date Between ' + @DateFrom + ' And ' + @DateTo + ' And
```

You need to CAST/CONVERT your datetime variables to nvarchar, and surround them with single-quotes.

Comment: Thank you for your guide , My issue is resolved by your guide